# jQuery date time picker not working while changing the timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, jquery-events, jquerydatetimepicker

datetimepicker is not working

I have a website where if the user clicks the button, then the timer which displays in the UI  will get changed by 20 minutes,
but when I do that it is not working.

Here is my code:

**Function called while clicking the button.**

I done this by removing previous timer class and added new timer class for increasing the timer.

```
function check(element) {
 (('input[name$="timer[[1]]"').addClass('increaseTimer').removeClass('inputTimer'));
}
```

My input element:

[image]

Input timer code:

```
$(".increaseTimer").datetimepicker({
  ignoreReadonly:true,
  format: 'LT',
  defaultDate: genDate()+' 00:20'
});
```

Increase timer code:

```
$(".inputTimer").datetimepicker({
  ignoreReadonly:true,
  format: 'LT',
  defaultDate: genDate()+' 00:00'
});
```

While inspecting, the class name has been changed but it doesn't change the timer in the UI,
but the same code works if I removed the inputtimer from the input type like this:

[image]

after that when I click the button then it calls the increase timer function and increases the timer by 20.

So what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You are missing `$` and have weird parenthesies: `(('input[name$="timer[[1]]"').addClass('increaseTimer').removeClass('inputTimer'));` should be `$('input[name$="timer[[1]]"').addClass('increaseTimer').removeClass('inputTimer');`

Comment: @mplungjan i have changed, still the same, the increaseTimer is not getting called?

Comment: it getting called only when i remove the input timer from the ui itself